# published property class in delphi component

Tags: delphi

I am having a problem creating a lookup component.

I will try again ... put the images to facilitate ....

does not save the values of properties in the dfm ... so why, my properties are grouped in a class ... if they were "loose" would perform the setter method ...

my doubt is ... why not run?

I thank you ...

My class of properties

```
TLookupProperties = class(TPersistent)
private
  FDataCharCase: TEditCharCase;
  FOnLookupBeforeSearch: TNotifyEvent;
  FDataSource: TDataSource;
  FOnButtonClick: TNotifyEvent;
  FDataTabela: string;
  FOnExit: TNotifyEvent;
  FDataCondicao: string;
  FDataFieldDescricao: string;
  FDataFieldCodigo: string;
  FOnLookupValidate: TNotifyEvent;
  FDataFieldID: String;
published
  property OnLookupBeforeSearch: TNotifyEvent read FOnLookupBeforeSearch write FOnLookupBeforeSearch;
  property OnLookupExit: TNotifyEvent read FOnExit write FOnExit;
  property OnLookupButtonClick: TNotifyEvent read FOnButtonClick write FOnButtonClick;
  property OnLookupValidate: TNotifyEvent read FOnLookupValidate write FOnLookupValidate;

  property DataSource: TDataSource read FDataSource write FDataSource;
  property DataFieldID: String read FDataFieldID write FDataFieldID;
  property DataFieldCodigo: string read FDataFieldCodigo write FDataFieldCodigo;
  property DataFieldDescricao: string read FDataFieldDescricao write FDataFieldDescricao;
  property Condicao: string read FDataCondicao write FDataCondicao;
  property Tabela: string read FDataTabela write FDataTabela;
  property CharCase: TEditCharCase read FDataCharCase write FDataCharCase;
end;
```

My component

```
TDBLookupFrame = class(TFrame)
  PnlTotal: TPanel;
  btnButton: TSpeedButton;
  edtCodigo: TDBEdit;
  lblDescricao: TDBText;
  procedure edtCodigoExit(Sender: TObject);
  procedure btnButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
  procedure edtCodigoKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
  procedure edtCodigoKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
strict private
  procedure SetarResult(AZerar: Boolean = False);
  procedure Validar(Sender: TObject);
private
  FLookupView: TLookupView;
  FLookupProperties: TLookupProperties;
  procedure SetLookupProperties(const Value: TLookupProperties);
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  destructor Destroy; override;
published
  property LookupProperties: TLookupProperties read FLookupProperties write SetLookupProperties;
end;

procedure register;

implementation

uses System.SysUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Hebran',[TDBLookupFrame]);
end;

procedure TDBLookupFrame.SetLookupProperties(const Value:   TLookupProperties);
begin
  FLookupProperties := Value;
  edtCodigo.CharCase := FLookupProperties.CharCase;
  FLookupView.Tabela := FLookupProperties.Tabela;
  FLookupView.CondicaoAdicional := FLookupProperties.Condicao;
  if Assigned(FLookupProperties.DataSource) then
  begin
    edtCodigo.DataSource := FLookupProperties.DataSource;
    lblDescricao.DataSource := FLookupProperties.DataSource;
    FLookupProperties.DataFieldDescricao :=      FLookupProperties.DataFieldCodigo;
   lblDescricao.DataField := FLookupProperties.DataFieldDescricao;
  end;
end;

constructor TDBLookupFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FLookupView := TLookupView.Create(Nil);
  FLookupProperties := TLookupProperties.Create;
  LookupProperties.Condicao := '';
  LookupProperties.CharCase := ecNormal; 
end;
```

Comment: That's obviously not your entire code.  Please add the rest of your code to the q; don't expect readers to guess what is in the parts your left out.  Meanwhile, -1.  Btw, I've removed irrelevant "registrar" tag.

Comment: Thanks for adding more code. Can you also show the constructor of `TDBLookupFrame` and `SetLookupProperties` as well? You can also remove `register` as it's completely irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help ... I'm getting used to this board ...

my English is bad

Comment: `SetLookupProperties` *should* be just a simple and single line `FLookupProperties.Assign(Value);` and then `TLookupProperties` should override the `Assign` procedure. Not entirely sure yet if that's your issue though.

Comment: the way it is implemented, the values are saved in the dfm, however, when using the component and close the Delphi ... to reopen the mistakes ... "error reading DBLookupFrame.LookupProperties.DataSource does not exists" ...
It seems I need to register the LookupProperties ... something ...

Comment: No, you can't register a `TPersistent`. I don't have access to an IDE to test your code, but when streaming your DFM into your component, it directly calls `SetLookupProperties` which is why I suggested you should include it. You really should be using `Assign` though.

Comment: @MartynA See OP's edit and my answer.

Comment: I have just spent over an hour trying to set up a project to replicate this but have found that I'm still having to guess far too much.  Imo, you need to edit your q to include the entire code, correctly split up into units as your source is **and** include the contents of your DFM (Form and Frame).[cont]

Comment: To debug this, it might be easiest to run one instance of the IDE inside another instance (a standard technique when debugging components)

Comment: @MartynA Doesn't the same work if you have both projects open in a project group?

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Sorry, no idea, but I don't really see how it could, as I'd have thought you'd need the second instance to see what the first instance does when creating the component instance to open the project.   I.e. it's the IDE you want to debug, not the project. I've always done this (since D4 or so) by running a second instance.

Comment: I appreciate everyone's help ...

My project depends on the operation of this component, and I confess I'm a little desperate ...

my component has no dependency with other external class (another package) ...
I could send some of you to analyze (if not abused, and not too much to ask) ...

just install the package (in Delphi xe8) and adicionalo in a form any ...
Link it to a datasource and save .... close the Delphi and after this, reopen the form ...

Comment: @JerryDodge: "*when streaming your DFM into your component, it directly calls SetLookupProperties*" - no , it does not. DFM streaming bypasses object property setters. `SetLookupProperties()` WILL NOT be called during streaming. The streaming will read the `LookupProperties` property to get the `TLookupProperties` object pointer and then stream its individual sub-properties directly instead. This is how DFM streaming has always worked.

Answer (score 2):

Looking here (which is called while streaming the DFM into your component):

```
procedure TDBLookupFrame.SetLookupProperties(const Value:   TLookupProperties);
begin
  FLookupProperties := Value;
  edtCodigo.CharCase := FLookupProperties.CharCase;
  FLookupView.Tabela := FLookupProperties.Tabela;
  FLookupView.CondicaoAdicional := FLookupProperties.Condicao;
  if Assigned(FLookupProperties.DataSource) then
  begin
    edtCodigo.DataSource := FLookupProperties.DataSource;
    lblDescricao.DataSource := FLookupProperties.DataSource;
    FLookupProperties.DataFieldDescricao :=      FLookupProperties.DataFieldCodigo;
   lblDescricao.DataField := FLookupProperties.DataFieldDescricao;
  end;
end;
```

You are calling

```
FLookupProperties := Value;
```

Indeed, when relying on the IDE to auto-complete this for you, it too adds this. However, based on your situation, you should not be assigning a pointer - because you're now referencing the original instance of `TLookupProperties` and replacing the pointer to your copy. This also leaks memory, You already created `FLookupProperties` in the constructor, but can't reference that instance anymore because you've replaced the pointer.

You should instead be calling

```
FLookupProperties.Assign(Value);
```

This will ensure you create a full copy of the original value instead of just referencing the instance (which may or may not have been free'd after that point).

Your `TLookupProperties` should also be overriding `TPersistent.Assign` so that you can perform the appropriate copying of data from one instance to the other. Again, for any type of other `TPersistent` properties, don't use `:=` because that just copies the pointer. Instead, use `.Assign` on them as well.

Comment: In fact, this did not solve ...
For my testing here has not changed ...

When I make the allocation of values in TLookupProperties property, they are saved in the dfm, but not their values can not be loaded when you open the form in a second time

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with saving. Indeed it saves just fine. Your problem is when loading it back, which is calling `SetLookupProperties`. This still is something you absolutely ***must*** do, but since I can't see how you've implemented it, I'm not sure why it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: I add the values in properties as the image in the link .. http://prntscr.com/8anbqv

then when I close the Delphi and open again from this error ...
http://prntscr.com/8anczn

Comment: LookupProperties my property to be registered ... because it does not there is more to reopen the Delphi ... http://prntscr.com/8anfe2

Comment: Could it be that you're still using an old compiled version of your component? Have you tried cleaning and re-building your package?

Comment: Sure, but that's not what I mean. Did you try re-building and re-installing it?

Comment: @JerryDodge:  I could be wrong, but I'm not sure that the streaming-in you mention at the start will occur unless the frame is registered as a component, rather than just as a frame template in the IDE (as a frame template is how a frame is usually  added to the IDE's component palette, iirc).

Comment: @JerryDodge: You are right that `TLookupProperties` needs to implement `Assign()`, but you are wrong that `SetLookupProperties()` is called during DFM loading - it is not. The DFM system will *read* the `TDBLookupFrame.LookupProperties` property to get its object pointer and then stream in its individual sub-properties, completely bypassing `SetLookupProperties()`.

Answer (score 2):

Try something more like this instead:

```
interface

uses
  Classes, Forms, ...;

type
  TDBLookupFrame = class;

  TLookupProperties = class(TPersistent)
  private
    FOwner: TDBLookupFrame;
    FDataCharCase: TEditCharCase;
    FDataSource: TDataSource;
    FDataTabela: string;
    FDataCondicao: string;
    FDataFieldDescricao: string;
    FDataFieldCodigo: string;
    FDataFieldID: String;
    FOnChange: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnButtonClick: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnExit: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnLookupBeforeSearch: TNotifyEvent;
    FOnLookupValidate: TNotifyEvent;
    procedure Changed;
    procedure SetDataSource(const: Value: TDataSource);
    procedure SetDataFieldID(const Value: String);
    procedure SetDataFieldCodigo(const Value: string);
    procedure SetDataFieldDescricao(const Valu: string);
    procedure SetCondicao(const Value: string);
    procedure SetTabela(const Value: string);
    procedure SetCharCase(const Value: TEditCharCase);
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TDBLookupFrame);
    procedure Assign(Source: TPeristent); override;
  published
    property DataSource: TDataSource read FDataSource write SetDataSource;
    property DataFieldID: String read FDataFieldID write SetDataFieldID;
    property DataFieldCodigo: string read FDataFieldCodigo write SetDataFieldCodigo;
    property DataFieldDescricao: string read FDataFieldDescricao write SetDataFieldDescricao;
    property Condicao: string read FDataCondicao write SetDataCondicao;
    property Tabela: string read FDataTabela write SetDataTabela;
    property CharCase: TEditCharCase read FDataCharCase write SetDataCharCase;

    property OnChange: TNotifyEvent read FOnChange write FOnChange;
    property OnLookupBeforeSearch: TNotifyEvent read FOnLookupBeforeSearch write FOnLookupBeforeSearch;
    property OnLookupExit: TNotifyEvent read FOnExit write FOnExit;
    property OnLookupButtonClick: TNotifyEvent read FOnButtonClick write FOnButtonClick;
    property OnLookupValidate: TNotifyEvent read FOnLookupValidate write FOnLookupValidate;
  end;

  TDBLookupFrame = class(TFrame)
    PnlTotal: TPanel;
    btnButton: TSpeedButton;
    edtCodigo: TDBEdit;
    lblDescricao: TDBText;
    procedure edtCodigoExit(Sender: TObject);
    procedure btnButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    procedure edtCodigoKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
    procedure edtCodigoKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
  strict private
    procedure SetarResult(AZerar: Boolean = False);
    procedure Validar(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FLookupView: TLookupView;
    FLookupProperties: TLookupProperties;
    procedure LookupPropertiesChanged(Sender: TObject);
    procedure SetLookupProperties(const Value: TLookupProperties);
  protected
    procedure Loaded; override;
    procedure Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation); override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property LookupProperties: TLookupProperties read FLookupProperties write SetLookupProperties;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

uses
  System.SysUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TLookupProperties.Create(AOwner: TDBLookupFrame);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FOwner := AOwner;
  FDataCondicao := '';
  FDataCharCase := ecNormal;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.Changed;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnChange) then
    FOnChange(Self);
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.SetDataSource(const: Value: TDataSource);
begin
  if FDataSource <> Value then
  begin
    if FDataSource <> nil then
      FDataSource.RemoveFreeNotification(FOwner);
    FDataSource := Value;
    if FDataSource <> nil then
      FDataSource.FreeNotification(FOwner);
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.SetDataFieldID(const Value: String);
begin
  if FDataFieldID <> Value then
  begin
    FDataFieldID := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.SetDataFieldCodigo(const Value: string);
begin
  if FDataFieldCodigo <> Value then
  begin
    FDataFieldCodigo := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.SetDataFieldDescricao(const Valu: string);
begin
  if FDataFieldDescricao <> Value then
  begin
    FDataFieldDescricao := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.SetCondicao(const Value: string);
begin
  if FDataCondicao <> Value then
  begin
    FDataCondicao := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.SetTabela(const Value: string);
begin
  if FDataTabela <> Value then
  begin
    FDataTabela := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.SetCharCase(const Value: TEditCharCase);
begin
  if FDataCharCase <> Value then
  begin
    FDataCharCase := Value;
    Changed;
  end;
end;

procedure TLookupProperties.Assign(Source: TPeristent);
var
  Src: TLookupProperties;
begin
  if Source is TLookupProperties then
  begin
    Src := TLookupProperties(Source);
    FDataCharCase := Src.FDataCharCase;
    SetDataSource(Src.FDataSource);
    FDataTabela := Src.FDataTabela;
    FDataCondicao := Src.FDataCondicao;
    FDataFieldDescricao := Src.FDataFieldDescricao;
    FDataFieldCodigo := Src.FDataFieldCodigo;
    FDataFieldID := Src.FDataFieldID;
    Changed;
  end else
    inherited;
end;

constructor TDBLookupFrame.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  FLookupView := TLookupView.Create(nil);
  FLookupProperties := TLookupProperties.Create(Self);
end;

destructor TDBLookupFrame.Destroy;
begin
  FLookupView.Free;
  FLookupProperties.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TDBLookupFrame.Loaded;
begin
  inherited;
  LookupPropertiesChanged(nil);
end;

procedure TDBLookupFrame.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
  inherited;
  if (AComponent = FLookupProperties.FDataSource) and (Operation = opRemove) then
    FLookupProperties.FDataSource := nil;
end;

procedure TDBLookupFrame.LookupPropertiesChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (ComponentState * [csLoading, csReading]) <> [] then
    Exit;

  edtCodigo.CharCase := FLookupProperties.CharCase;
  FLookupView.Tabela := FLookupProperties.Tabela;
  FLookupView.CondicaoAdicional := FLookupProperties.Condicao;

  edtCodigo.DataSource := FLookupProperties.DataSource;
  lblDescricao.DataSource := FLookupProperties.DataSource;
  FLookupProperties.DataFieldDescricao := FLookupProperties.DataFieldCodigo;
  lblDescricao.DataField := FLookupProperties.DataFieldDescricao;
end;

procedure TDBLookupFrame.SetLookupProperties(const Value:   TLookupProperties);
begin
  if FLookupProperties <> Value then
    FLookupProperties.Assign(Value);
end;

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Hebran', [TDBLookupFrame]);
end;
```

Comment: thank you for your help my friend ...
but i do not understand some things ...

I do not have access to FOwner In TLookupProperties.SetdataSource...

DoChange is Changed in TLookupProperties.Assign, is correct?;        
Sorry for my ignorance ... but my knowledge is still limited and am improving ...

Comment: My bad. I had started adding `FOwner` and then removed it and forgot that `SetDataSource()` was still using it.  I have added it back in now.

Comment: Thanks again friend ...

Added its solution in my code, but now, to add my component on a form, there is an accessory Violation ... Still have not figured out why ...

Answer (score 0):

sorry but my example is simple ... the problem is that the class does not perform the set of property TProperties class, then, does not save the values in .dfm to put the dataSource and dataField properties directly on my component, it performs the set and writes to the dfm, however, when you open a form with my component, property values saved in the dfm are not found ... (error Ex: property datasource not found)

Comment: You need to add this to your question by editing it, not by posting an answer. This is not an answer.